# Intent used in ExpandablesListView

Tags: android, expandablelistview

I have an ExpandableListView and while it expands on clicking on the parent ListView, there is a list of items that appear on the child listView. On clicking I want those items to intent to another activity. Can anyone suggest me the code where I do not have to use the **switch** case or if-else statements. Here is my code

```
expListView = (ExpandableListView) findViewById(R.id.lvExp);

            // preparing list data
            prepareListData();

            listAdapter = new ExpandableListAdapter(this, listDataHeader, listDataChild);

            // setting list adapter
            expListView.setAdapter(listAdapter);

            // Listview Group click listener
            expListView.setOnGroupClickListener(new OnGroupClickListener() {

                @Override
                public boolean onGroupClick(ExpandableListView parent, View v,
                        int groupPosition, long id) {
                    // Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                    // "Group Clicked " + listDataHeader.get(groupPosition),
                    // Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    return false;
                }
            });

            // Listview Group expanded listener
            expListView.setOnGroupExpandListener(new OnGroupExpandListener() {

                @Override
                public void onGroupExpand(int groupPosition) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                            listDataHeader.get(groupPosition) + " Expanded",
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            });

            // Listview Group collasped listener
            expListView.setOnGroupCollapseListener(new OnGroupCollapseListener() {

                @Override
                public void onGroupCollapse(int groupPosition) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                            listDataHeader.get(groupPosition) + " Collapsed",
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                }
            });

            // Listview on child click listener
            expListView.setOnChildClickListener(new OnChildClickListener() {

                @Override
                public boolean onChildClick(ExpandableListView parent, View v,
                        int groupPosition, int childPosition, long id) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    Toast.makeText(
                            getApplicationContext(),
                            listDataHeader.get(groupPosition)
                                    + " : "
                                    + listDataChild.get(
                                            listDataHeader.get(groupPosition)).get(
                                            childPosition), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                            .show();
                    return false;
                }
            });
        }
```

I want intent in place of toast in the onChildClickListener.

Comment: then how will you find the position. you have to do like if(groupPosition==0 && childpPosition == 1){intent to some activity}

Comment: Can't it be done if I can create a array of string of all new activities in sequential order.

then I can get the activity name by arr[position] and call

Intent b = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), arr[pos]); startActivity(b);

Comment: The only question is how will u find which group or which groups's child is click ? You will check the position or not ?

Comment: so for that I'm getting the parent position(groupPosition) or not?

Comment: suggest me how will u do this, start Activity A for group 0 && child 1 and start Activity B for group 1 && child 0 ?

Answer (score 0):

Intent intent=new Intent();
intent.startActivity(YourCurrentClass.ContextofyourCurrentClass,Classtoswitch.class);

Comment: Can't it be done if I can create a array of string of all new activities in sequential order.

then I can get the activity name by arr[position] and call

Intent b = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), arr[pos]); startActivity(b);

Comment: You Mean you want that if you click on listitem one it goes to first activity your desire if you click on second then it goes to second activity like that

Comment: I think you want this  Activity[] act={Demo.class,MySwitch.class}; but it is impossible how much i practice you want to call the condition of switch as i know if you find any other solution better then switch or if else then let me know